# SQL, sum up totals of 3 columns from 3 tables and insert into 1 table with date and timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables that have have incidents, tableA tableB, tableC. I need the total of incidents from tableA.columnA, tableB.columnB, tableC.columnC and inserted into a 3rd table which will accumulate the data over time.

This is what I am trying, the commands complete but the data does not move over.

```
DECLARE @data INT = 1;
WHILE @data = 1
BEGIN 
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tableA], [dbo].[tableB], [dbo].[tableC])
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[sixMonthReport]
SELECT *,  ,GETDATE() AS ImportDate, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DayofData
FROM [dbo].[tableA], [dbo].[tableB], [dbo].[tableC] 
SET @data = 0
END
ELSE
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'
END
```

sixMonthReport table was/is premade with the column names as needed which match up to those column names assigned in their original tables. Is it possible to have these 3 columns calculate their sums, and go into separate columns in the third table with a date/timestamp? (I am aware that it is going to stamp it with the date/time of when the command is ran and also the previous day.)

Here is what the tables look like:

```
## TableA ##
----------
totalAincidents
14
13
11

## TableB ##
----------
totalBincidents
15
14
15

## TableC ##
----------
totalCindidents
16
15
15

## sixMonthReport ##
-----------
totalAincidents | totalBincidents | totalCincidents | totalIncidents | daterecorded | yesterday's date
-----------
38              | 44 | 46 | 128 | jan 20 | jan 19
```

hope this helps

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample data and desired results.  I doubt a Cartesian product is actually desirable.

Comment: I edited it a bit to show how I was needing it to kind of look. I will try your answer now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the current counts from each table, then perhaps the best way is subqueries.  The query would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO sixMonthReport(ImportDate, DayofData, aval, bval, cval)
    SELECT GETDATE() AS ImportDate, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DayofData,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA),
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableB),
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableC);
```

I wouldn't use an `IF` clause for this.  Just insert the data.  If the tables are empty, you'll get `0`.

Comment: Question seemed hard to me,but you made answer look easy :)

Comment: this time it was successful and data populated however in the aval bval and cbal columns, there is only "1" for each column. which there should be 13, 14, 2. I'm sure I did something incorrectly, I assumed aval is the actual name of the column same with bval and cval?

Comment: I got it figured out by changing some of what you suggested to:

(SELECT SUM() FROM ),
 (SELECT SUM() FROM ,
 (SELECT SUM() FROM );